# Java Character removal of a string

Tags: java, string

How should I go about removing the two characters "[" and "]" from a string

```
Example: [45.677]

Desired: 45.677
```

I would preferably like to preform this in on single handed method call. Moreover, **Not two str.replace() calls.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regex

```
string.replaceAll("\\[|\\]","");
```

Comment: You need to escape the `[`.

Answer (score 2):

use below regex:

```
 System.out.println( "[45.677]".replaceAll("\\[|]",""));
```

as `[` is a special character(meta character) you should escape it with backslash in order to treat it as a normal character. thus  `\\[`

Comment: You have to escape the `]` symbol too.

Comment: checked, to my surprise. I thought that `]` was a metacharacter (as the opening `[` is. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using `replaceAll`, if the `[]` chars are in the same position always (start and end of the string) then also you could use:

```
string.substring(1, string.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("[45.677]".replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", ""));
```